# partial row-sums in multidimensional arrays

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

I have a question on how to apply R functions to multidimensional arrays.

For example, consider this operation, where I reduce an entry by the sum of other entries.

```
ppl["2012",,,,,1] <- ppl["2012",,,,,1]
- ppl["2012",,,,,2] - ppl["2012",,,,,3] - ppl["2012",,,,,4]
- ppl["2012",,,,,5] - ppl["2012",,,,,6] - ppl["2012",,,,,7]
- ppl["2012",,,,,8]
```

While in this case subtracting individual values might be feasible, I would prefer a vector-oriented approach.

If I was familiar with multidimensional matrix algebra I could probably come up with the matrix that performs the necessary operation when applied, but this is too complex given the number of dimensions involved.

`sum(ppl["2012",,,,,2:8])` is not the correct solution, as `sum()` always returns scalars.

I could use loops that perform the necessary operations, but that contradicts the paradigm of vector-oriented programming.

Thanks for your help!

Edit: And here is the solution to the original problem, based on Andrie's suggestion:
`ppl[paste(i),land,,,,1] <- ppl[paste(i),land,,,,1] - apply(ppl[paste(i),land,,,,2:8],c(1,2,3),sum)`

Comment: You need to use `apply` with `sum` to get what you want. However, as you did not provide an example **with data**, I am unable to give you the exact code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDITED**

Here is an example of using `apply` and `sum` to return the sum computed across a multi-dimensional table:

```
mat <- array(1:27, dim=c(3, 3, 3))
```

Let's say you'd like to compute the sum of the third dimension for each combination of the first two dimension.

Then the code to do this becomes:

```
apply(mat, c(1,2), sum)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   30   39   48
[2,]   33   42   51
[3,]   36   45   54
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Indeed, those two sums are identical, but I do not want to subtract the total sum.

Instead, I want to calculate for every year, every country, every household composition etc. the sum of values in the last dimension.

Comment: @Martin Zuba, thank you for your comment.  I have modified my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Yes, that is what I need! Some sort of sum algorithm, that will return a result with one dimension less than that of the original set. Thanks a lot!